# iOS Admob loadRequest memory

Tags: ios, admob

`xcode7.1`, `iOS9.1`, Admob version `7.5.2`
Admob `loadrequest` memory leak

```
    bannerView = GADBannerView(frame: rectBanner)
    bannerView.adUnitID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    bannerView.rootViewController = self
    request = GADRequest()
    bannerView.loadRequest(request)
    coverBanner.addSubview(bannerView)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm experiencing exactly the same thing! Did you solve it?

Comment: @NJanf I gave some guess, if it's still not working, please provide more codes or open a new question with more information.

Answer (score 0):

Are you removing the previous add from the parent view when you receive a new ad? If you don't remove the previous ad, it definitely could give you a memory leak. You could use `removeFromSuperview`and try. That should help.